# Select multiple times using LINQ based on result

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have this dataset

[This is the current dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVljy.png)

So, I am trying to return the data based on the Category Id as an input. But if keyword is not present for the category, then the data from its parent should be returned

This is an example

Input: 202; Output: ParentCategoryID=201, Name=Operating System,
Keywords=Teaching

This is what I have right now (testData is the dataset)

```
public static string GetData(int categoryId)
    {
        var searchResult = testData.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId).FirstOrDefault();

        //if has no keywords return parent data
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchResult.Keywords))
            {
                var parentData = testData.Where(x => x.CategoryId == searchResult.ParentCategoryId);

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.Append("ParentCategoryId=");
                stringBuilder.Append(parentData.ParentCategoryId);
                stringBuilder.Append(", Name=");
                stringBuilder.Append(parentData.Name);
                stringBuilder.Append(", Keywords=");
                stringBuilder.Append(parentData.Keywords);

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
```

But this only works with just one parent. It works in this kind of scenarios

Input: 201; Output: ParentCategoryID=200, Name=Computer,
Keywords=Teaching

I think there is an issue with my LINQ query, I would appreciate any advice

Comment: sounds like you need loop or recursion

Answer (score 0):

A simple while loop might be what you need

```
int input = 202;
bool flag = true;
var result = datalist.Where(q => q.CatId == input).FirstOrDefault();
var parrent = datalist.Where(q => q.CatId == result.ParrentId).FirstOrDefault();

var keyword = "";
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parrent.Keyword))
{
    parrent = datalist.Where(q => q.CatId == parrent.ParrentId).FirstOrDefault();
}
keyword = parrent.Keyword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent via a recursive function:

```
public static WhateverYourDataTypeIs GetParent(int parentCategoryId)
        var parentData = testData.Where(x => x.CategoryId == parentCategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentData.Keywords))
        {
            return GetParent(parentData.ParentCategoryId);
        }
        return parentData;
}
```

And just call that instead of the old way you got the parent

```
// OLD: 
var parentData = testData.Where(x => x.CategoryId == searchResult.ParentCategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
// NEW: 
var parentData = GetParent(searchResult.ParentCategoryId)
```